# How can I do edit-and-continue in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, geoprocessing, modelbuilder

I'm constructing a model in ModelBuilder, and I ran into an error with one of my tools. I fixed the error and want to continue running my model from that step onward without having to repeat the entire model. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you still have your model open (in design view), yes.  If you have closed your model, or ran it from the dialog, no.

If your model is still open in design view, the model should have failed and the last action run correctly should have a grey "shading" underneath it.  You should be able to just press "Run" and it will begin again.

This process is described in the ArcGIS Online Help: [Running a model within ModelBuilder](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002w0000003p000000)

Comment: Great, thank you. This is perfect. I didn't come across that page, for some reason. I'm using Arc 10, and this points to 10.1's help. I'm sure it's in both, but I just didn't catch it. Thanks!